# Can an Oath of Redemption Paladin using Emissary of Redemption cast buffs on allies?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin

In *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, the Oath of Redemption Paladin's capstone ability, Emissary of Redemption, stops working under the following conditions:

> If you attack a creature, **cast a spell on it**, or deal damage
>   to it by any means but this feature, neither benefit
>   works against that creature until you finish a long rest.

Is this intended to imply RAW that an Oath of Redemption Paladin can't cast buff spells on their party? What are their options in combat to avoid losing this ability for the day?

Comment: Hello and welcome! If you have time please take the [tour] to find out more about the site. It seems that you have found a starting point to a [self-answered question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) but the answer in particular looks like it could use some work. Checking [this blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) should help.

Answer (score 6):

### Emissary of Redemption is tracked by creature

The benefit only stops working on each creature that the paladin attacks, casts a spell on or deals damage to (emphasis mine):

> If you attack a creature, cast a spell on it, or deal damage to it by any means but this feature, neither benefit works **against that creature** until you finish a long rest.

This means that casting beneficial spells on allies simply makes only them to no longer be affected by Emissary of Redemption. Unless you are worried that these allies might deal damage to you for some reason this should not be a problem.